# Access 2003 form borders won't stay sized correctly

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am working on an Access 2003 form and the borders keep resizing themselves so the form doesn't fit!  It's driving me crazy!  It seems to happen when I go into design mode.  No matter how many times I drag the edges and save the form, it always seems to want to resize to some arbitrary size!

I have AutoResize turned off.

Any ideas why this happens or how to fix it?

Comment: It gets resized.  It seems as though every time I go back into design view, it loses ~1/2 inch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter design view, your border is probably larger than what you want it to be, and then once you exit design view into Form view again, you see the extra space.

A trick that helps me with that usually, is to size the window exactly how you want it (you will probably go back and forth between design and form view to make sure you like the size), and then go to design view one last time, hit save, go to form view again, and hit save again. Then close the form.

Also, I prefer to set the MinMaxButtons property to 'none' and the border style to 'dialog'. That way, users can't just jump in there and start resizing all of your carefully sized windows :)

Comment: This worked great!  I was under the false assumption that setting the border type to Dialog made the form modal.  I set it to dialog and it's saving the size correctly now!  Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! I always hate it when the little weird things like that hold me up.

Answer (score 2):

If it's helpful, you can set the size and position of your form with VBA code in the form's On Open event.

In addition to controlling the position of your form, the [Form.Move Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff845906.aspx) will allow you to set its size by assigning your values (in twips, where 1440 twips/inch) to the *Width* and *Height* parameters.

Comment: The problem with that method is that different versions of Windows and different Office Themes have different chrome dimensions. For instance, the title bar is completely different height in WinXP's Classic skin than in the hideous Luna skin. I have never had good results with manually resizing forms.

Comment: (by "manually resizing" I mean resizing in code, setting the dimensions in TWIPS; I use code I got from Stephen Lebans)